# Why can I use an empty value `[]` for a typed array interface but not an empty `{}` for a typed object interface?

Tags: typescript

I noticed I can initialize friends below as an empty array `[]` but I can't do the same for session with an empty object `{}`. Why is this and is there any way to use the empty object without making all the keys optional in the interface?

```
const initialState: {
  friends: Array<{
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }>;
  session: {
    login: string;
    avatar: string;
  }
} = {
  friends: [], // all good
  session: {}  // throws error!
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `[]` is still a valid array (of length zero) for `Array<{name:string;age:number;}>`.

But `{}` is not a valid object of the form `{login: string; avatar: string}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object `let x = {}` and you set `x.login = "name"` you've just changed the format of the object. Now an array of a given type can still be considered such if empty.

If you want an interface that would accept both objects `{}` and `{login: string, avatar: string}`, you can use:

```
interface GenericObject {
  [property: string]: any;
}
```

Use it with care though, if you wanted objects in any format you likely wouldn't be typing your code in the first place.